# Convert shadow to path sketch 3

Tags: sketch-app

Is it possible to convert the shadow of a element to a path and then flatten it in sketch 3? 
[image: sketch screenshot]

Comment: I've never used Sketch, so I don't know if this option exists in that program.  In Illustrator, you would accomplish this by selecting Expand Appearance from the Object menu.  Maybe Sketch has a similar command?

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**
No

**Long answer:**
To do what you're trying to do in Sketch 3 (3.1 if you just updated today), is by duplicating the gear path, nudging the bottom layer down, and changing the fill color.

Two layers, no shadows, but you get the desired effect.

I wish there was a way to do what you want to do though. That being said, the Sketch team is pretty receptive to feedback:

[image: menu]
[image: window]

Answer (score 0):

There's a [plugin](https://github.com/jayholtslander/sketch-make-long-shadow) for creating *long shadows*.